# Prevent user from pasting line break

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently having an issue with a code. In my code, I've got a textarea where the user can enter the title of an article and I would like this article to be only in one row. That's why I wrote a script to prevent users to press the return key. But they could bypass this security, indeed if they copy/past the line break they could enter a line break. So, is there a way to detect line break ? I suppose we can do this with regular expressions and with \n or \n. However I tried this:

```
var enteredText = $('textarea[name="titleIdea"]').val();
var match = /\r|\n/.exec(enteredText);
if (match) {

    alert('working');
}
```

and it doesn't work for an unknown reason. I think the **var enteredText = $('textarea[name="titleIdea"]').val();** doesn't work because when I try to alert() it, it shows nothing. But something strange is that when I do an alert on $('textarea[name="titleIdea"]').val(); and not on the enteredText variable it shows the content.
Have a great day. (sorry for mistakes, I'm french)

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't using a text field? Try adding  some console.log() statements into your code to see where it breaks:

console.log(enteredText);
var match = /\r|\n/.exec(enteredText);

Comment: @Wes `console.log` isn't a statement, but a function.

Comment: You really should be choosing your input types according to the data you expect. The first rule of UI design is to make it obvious what type of data you are expecting. In agreement with @Wes you should be using an input field of type text. Text area makes the user think multi-line is okay. For the selector, I believe the inner quotes should be single quotes, though you can always just add an id to the element and select it by id.

Comment: _"But they could bypass this security"_ - everything you do only client-side is far from "security." (It would be naive to even assume that every request that reaches your script would have to come from a "browser.") Do this server-side - either reject the data if it contains line breaks, or filter them out automatically.

Comment: @TheProHands Thanks for the clarification - I always think of `console.log()` like a `print_r` statement. But technically you are correct. Not that it helps answer this question...

Answer (score 1):

> if they copy/past the line break they could enter a line break

That's why you shouldn't even worry about preventing them from entering it - just don't save it.  Remove it on the `blur` and `input` events if you really want to, but the only time it actually matters is before you save it to the database (or whatever you are using).

```
$('textarea[name="titleIdea"]').on('blur input', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""));
});
```

And, as other people have already mentioned, if they can't do line breaks, you shouldn't be using a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is with the paste event.

If i guessed this is my snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('textarea[name="titleIdea"]').on('paste', function(e) {
    var data;
    
    if (window.clipboardData) { // for IE
      data = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    } else {
      data = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    }
    
    var match = /\r|\n/.exec(data);
    if (match) {

      alert('working');
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<textarea name="titleIdea">

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be handled in the backend. Even if you use the recommended appropriate HTML input type of text (instead of textarea), you still do not remove the possibility of return chars getting saved.

The two other answers use Javascript - which technically is the domain of this question. However, this can not be solved with Javascript! This assumes that the input will always come from the form you created with the JS function working perfectly.

The only way to avoid specific characters being inserted into your database is to parse and clean the data in the backend language prior to inserting into your database.

For example, if you are using PHP, you could run a similar regex that stripped out the \n\r chars before it went into processing.

Javascript only helps the UX in this case (the user sees what they will be saving). But the only way to ensure you have data integrity is to validate it on the server side.